# Running dotnet-isolated AzureFunction does not work

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have developed an Azure Function v4 with .net 6.0. It contains only http triggered functions.

Locally everything works fine, but after deploying it to Azure i only get 500 Status Code by calling any endpoint and it always throws `InvalidOperationException` at `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcherLoadBalancer.GetLanguageWorkerChannel` : **Did not find any initialized language workers**

- Application settings

[image]

- Operating System: Windows
- Runtime Version: 4.0.1.16815
- Location: West Europe

**Update** Add more information

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="11.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.20.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

local.settings.json

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
        "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage",
        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "MyInstrumentationKey"
    },
    "Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
        "CORS": "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does restarting the function app make any difference?

Comment: unfortunately: no

Comment: does not change anything :-(

Answer (score 1):

One of the workaround to resolve this issue:

1. Created Azure Functions (Stack: .Net 6 Isolated) in Visual Studio and run locally:

[image]

2. After deploying of Function App in the Azure Portal (Stack: .Net 6, Location: West Europe, OS: Windows, Plan: Consumption, Function Runtime: Isolated)

This is the configuration:
[image]

After deploying, the function URL is running successfully:

[image]

---

3. As I can see a setting called `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` is added into your .Net Function App Configuration Settings.

[image]

If your function is not created with node.js and if you are not using this application setting explicitly in your code then you can remove this property from your function app. This is stated in this [MSFT Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/393314/is-website-node-version-application-setting-requir.html).

4. The other reasons for this kind of error would be

   - The Functions Runtime is initialized but it failed to initialize the Language Worker. So, the Functions Runtime detects that the worker channel has not started and logs the error message on further invocations.

**Note:**
5. Try Re-creation of the Function App (.Net 6 - Windows OS- West Europe Location) in the Azure Portal and deploy your HTTP Trigger Function from Visual Studio.
Or
6. Try removing the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` setting > Save > Restart the app in the azure portal and run the function.
7. Make sure this setting is "`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated`" in your function app `local.settings.json` file.
8. This error may exist due to unmatching of Functions worker version and SDK version. If any updates available, please update them through NuGet Packet Manager:
[image]

Also, this error exist in previous version of dotnet Isolated is 5 and in Azure Functions Version V3.

**References:**

1. [azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues](https://gitmetadata.com/repo/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/556)
2. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7618.
3. [SO Thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086787/azure-function-failed-to-start-a-new-language-worker-for-runtime-dotnet-isola)

Comment: thx for the detailled answer.
The workaround doesn't change anything.

Comment: Worker packages are all up-to-date.
And Configuration settings are as you mentioned.
Removing the WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION also not changed anything.

Comment: @DerDani81 did you try to update the worker package versions in your function app if any updates are available and redeploy it.

Comment: And after removing `website_node_default_version` setting, could you please try re-publishing the function to the azure and check?

Comment: nothing changed after re-deploy.

Comment: @DerDani81 did you try to update the worker package versions in your function app if any updates are available? If the function worker runtime version is unmatched, then this kind of issue occurs sometimes.

Comment: worker packages are already up-to-date:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.0.0" /><PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241197/discussion-between-harikrishnarajoli-mt-and-derdani81).

Comment: @DerDani81, Any update to the issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I can't get any isolated function to work in Azure, but locally it runs fine.