# .NET7 Azure Functions: the host has not yet started

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I want to debug on my laptop a project with Azure Functions. The language is C#. Few functions are using a connection to a service bus. This project is deployed already on Azure and it is working.

In my new laptop, I have installed Visual Studio 2022 Community (64 bit) - Preview Version 17.5.0 Preview 6.0.

Then, pull the project from the Git repository and when I run the project I get this error

> A host error has occurred during startup operation '02312afe-22ad-4fdf-bb10-f4852471c73e'.
>
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Did not find functions with language [dotnet-isolated].

[image]

Visual Studio shows me those lines:

```
public Task StopAsync()
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();

    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _state, StateStoppingOrStopped, StateStarted);

    if (_state != StateStoppingOrStopped)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The host has not yet started.");
    }
```

that they are coming from `JobHost.cs` (wrote by Microsoft)

[image]

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70762049/running-dotnet-isolated-azurefunction-does-not-work), I tried to install the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools) but I get the same error.

The project has the following properties

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>
    <UserSecretsId>d9d1dbff-5ee9-4590-ab74-4fbd7c563096</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.8.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.0.0-preview4" />
    <PackageReference Include="PSC.Extensions" Version="6.0.28" />
    <PackageReference Include="WB.Domain" Version="1.2.44" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\WB.Api.Client\WB.Api.Client\WB.Api.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\WB.Connections.Reverso\WB.Connections.Reverso\WB.Connections.Reverso.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I tried to change in the `local.settings.json` the value `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` from `dotnet-isolated` to `powershell` but with the same issue.

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "powershell",
        "SBConnectionString": "Endpoint=myconection"
    }
}
```

So, then, I tried to create a new Azure Functions with Visual Studio with NET7. In the wizard I added the Service Bus connection string and the queue. The error is simular

[image]

### Azurite

If I use the PowerShell to run `Azurite` I get an error

[image]

When I open the project in Visual Studio I can see

[image]

Comment: Is your azure storage emulator started?

Answer (score 2):

In the Question Description, you have given the .NET 6 Azure Functions `.csproj` Code:

> [image]

If you're migrating to .NET 6/7 Isolated Version, you have to set the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` as `dotnet-isolated` in the `local.settings.json` file and follow the steps given in SO #[69104798](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70370806) by the user @*DwainBrowne*.

Below is the `.csproj` code for Azure Functions .NET 7 Isolated Version with Http and Service Bus Trigger:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0-preview2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

---

> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Did not find functions with language [dotnet-isolated].

Do not use the `powershell` value to the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` if the Functions Project is not in the PowerShell Language/Runtime.

---

> [image]

I have observed that you are getting the error in using the Service Bus Connection String such as `'Endpoint=sb://wbreverso.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;[Hidden Credential]' is missing or empty.`

This Error will come when the Service Bus Connection String Name is not the same from the `local.settings.json` to the Function Code.

You have defined the Service Bus Connection String in the variable `SBConnectionString` from the `local.settings.json` file and same name should be used in the Service Bus Trigger Function Declaration.

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", Connection = "SBConnectionString")]
```

This is for running the Service Bus Trigger Azure Functions in the local IDEs (Visual Studio, VS Code).

When you are running the same Function project in Azure Cloud, you have to define that service bus connection string in the Application Settings Configuration Section.

Refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=in-process,extensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#connections) for more information on Azure Functions Service Bus Trigger Connection Bindings.