# PowerShell Azure Function: How to fix "Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: powershell"?

Tags: powershell, azure-functions, powershell-core

In an Azure Function App containing one PowerShell function I get the following log message regularly:

`"Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: powershell."`

It has "Error" level and thus triggers our error alert notifications. I'm not entirely sure when this message appears. It might appear around restarting the function app, which might explain it somewhat. I think I remember it appearing during normal function operation - but I might be mistaken.

There is a rather involved thread over here about a similar message but for the dotnet runtime that suggests there are configuration options to configure: [Azure Function - Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68086787/azure-function-failed-to-start-a-new-language-worker-for-runtime-dotnet-isola)

My function app runtime version is ~4, PS Core version is 7.0, platform is 64 bit and Windows.

What is the error message trying to telling me? Can I ignore it? Is there a configuration I can add to fix it?

Comment: hii @heinrich Ulbricht, share more information about these problem.

Comment: @PunitSharma-MT Which information do you miss? I will add it.

Comment: you can share code and what way use to create PowerShell function (vs or azure portal).

Answer (score 0):

After monitoring this for a while over the course of multiple deployments and restarts of PowerShell-based Function Apps my conclusion is this:

The error `"Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: powershell."` only appears when restarting the Function App. Thus my takeaway is that it can be ignored.